# How to display partially bold text in QListWidgetItem with QtCore.Qt.UserRole

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, styling, qlistwidgetitem

I want to display a single word in a QListWidgetItem in bold font. According to this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247904/how-to-style-rich-text-in-qlistwidgetitem-and-qcombobox-items-pyqt-pyside), it should be possible to use `QtCore.Qt.UserRole` for this purpose. However, the sample code provided *did not work* for me. (Since I'm a beginner, I most likely forgot a definition, but I don't know which one.)

This is what I have so far:

**main.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>341</width>
    <height>244</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>321</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QListWidget" name="lwOptions"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**test.py**

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, uic
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QDialog, QListWidgetItem

class GUI(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(dirname,'main.ui'), self)

        # this doesn't work
        for ordinal in ['first', 'second', 'third']:
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            item.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, 'This is the <b>{}</b> word.'.format(ordinal)) 
            self.lwOptions.addItem(item)

        for ordinal in ['fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']:
            item = QListWidgetItem('This is the <b>{}</b> word.'.format(ordinal))
            self.lwOptions.addItem(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run the the code it'll add three empty lines and three lines with the verbatim messages.

What's the correct `QtCore.Qt.UserRole` syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roles `>= Qt::UserRole` are not used by Qt by default so it can be used for any purpose, for example to save additional information, in this case it is not the solution. One possible solution is to use a delegate to render the HTML.

```
import os
import html
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

class HTMLDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HTMLDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()
        options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        self.doc.setHtml(options.text)
        options.text = ""
        style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style() if options.widget is None \
            else options.widget.style()
        style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText))
        else:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text))
        textRect = style.subElementRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options, None)
        if index.column() != 0:
            textRect.adjust(5, 0, 0, 0)
        constant = 4
        margin = (option.rect.height() - options.fontMetrics.height()) // 2
        margin = margin - constant
        textRect.setTop(textRect.top() + margin)

        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)
        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QtCore.QSize(self.doc.idealWidth(), self.doc.size().height())

class GUI(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(dirname,'main.ui'), self)

        delegate = HTMLDelegate(self.lwOptions)
        self.lwOptions.setItemDelegate(delegate)

        for ordinal in ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']:
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem('This is the <b>{}</b> word.'.format(ordinal))
            self.lwOptions.addItem(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for another perfect solution!

Comment: @eyllanesc is it possible this example only covers ForegroundRole formatting- as in text color and text formatting, but doesn't help with BackgroundRole for background color?  i tried passing it <p style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #ff0000">foot</p> but the background color isn't taken care of by the delegate.  ... i also noticed that using BackgroundRole in the python model itselfl like this:             if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole: if True: return QtGui.QColor('red') did work, while attempting to set a color for the analagous ForegroundRole failed.  can you help me see why? tx